# How to detect that a request is originating from a Good Mobile browser

Tags: mobile, detection, browser-detection

We have a requirement to redirect the request to a mobile version of the app if it origniates from a mobile device.I'm using the existence of X-WAP-Profile in the header and it seems to work with Blackberry however when we try to test on Good (Secure Mobile) Browser it doesn't work.looks like the header is not on in this case.I'm accessing from iPhone.

So there are two questions

1. What is a conclusive way of recognising that the request is originating from the Good Browser
2. Will this change based on the kind of device that the Mobile browser is used from i.e iPad/iPhone/Android etc?

If there is a way to avoid the user-agent (assuming that they change from device/mobile os type) I would prefer that method of detection.

Any pointers in this regard please help

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, a http request, including its headers, is text, and this text can be anything a piece of software wants to send. So, I can easily have a mobile browser that reports itself as being a desktop browser. What this means is that there is no absolute and conclusive way of recognizing anything about the source of a request. All you can reasonably do is trust the user-agent string, and respond to as many different values as you can. If you're getting no value, then you'll have to make a decision on which version of the app to go to.

Comment: Agreed but USER AGENT based detection will lead to many rules and I'm not even sure if there is a difference in the user agent string if for instance you access from Chrome/Firefox and not from a laptop/desktop.For these kind of reasons I'm inclined to find if there is any specific header to look for. X-WAP-Profile looked to be from what I gathered going to be on all the mobile devices but that is apparently not the case as my redirection logic doesn't kick in when using the Good Browser from iPhone/iPad and hence the question.